# Looking for simple searchable DMS

Tags: search, document-management

We have a project with a looooot of documents (Word,Excel, TXT, Pdf, ...). Currently, we simply store it on a shared folder.

But it has soon become not manageable.

Do you know any simple open source (and free or cheap, even for commercial use) DMS that would enable to search within all these data ?

I already know about Alfresco and Nuxeo, but they are too heavy and with many features.

What I need is :

- 'Google like' search inside all MSOffice documents (title & content).
- Access via a standard shared folder (Webdav or so)
- Transparent versionning (optional)
- Tagging (optional)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... WSS comes to mind.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D51730B5-48FC-4CA2-B454-8DC2CAF93951&displaylang=en

Comment: second. sharepoint

Comment: Third. Sharepoint.

Comment: Thanks,

I wasn't aware that Sharepoint is included freely with Win 2003 server.
I will give it a try.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: FYI, we finally opted for a simple "Google Desktop" solution.
This is free and is enough for our needs.